# Two different samples from different time periods.

Tags: probability

I have a sample of grades from 1000 students.  The average mark was 60 with a standard deviation of 3.

A year later I collected a sample of grades from 50 students sitting the same test.  The average mark was 80 with a standard deviation of 4.

What is the best way to use these results to predict the expected average grade from another random sample of students (same time period as second sample)?

Should I use the first data set or the second, or some combination of the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard weighted averages use the square of the reciprocal of the deviation as their weight:

$$w_{1}=\frac{1}{3^2}=\frac{1}{9},w_{2}=\frac{1}{4^2}=\frac{1}{16}$$
The value then becomes
$$\frac{\sum_{i} w_{i} x_{i}}{\sum_{i}w_i}=\frac{\frac{1}{9}60+\frac{1}{16}80}{\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{16}}=67.2$$

Answer (score 0):

You have enough data to say with rather high assurance that the two test results did not come from the same distribution.  What would make you think the new sample comes from the same distribution as either of the other two ?  Did you have a different professor last year?  Did the students know the questions last year because it was the same test?  Probably the best you can do is use the new data and ignore the other.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, I want to assume that all conditions are the same for the students, except the period of time is separated by 1 year.  Now I agree the samples are statistically different, but the 1st sample had a much greater sample size, and thus might still have some weight on my future prediction, as the most recent sample could be an anomoly.

Comment: Well it depends if this is a critical thinking assignment or a simple statistics assignment.

Comment: @Feyre, just a thought experiment I invented myself.  I welcome the most technical answers.

Comment: @mew Sample size only means it's likely to have a slimmer standard deviation.
If no other data is available to interpret the data, simple statistics is the best you're gonna get.

Comment: @Feyre, does credibility theory apply here?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credibility_theory

Comment: @Mew, Sure, or simply the Null-hypothesis, which you won't be able to reject. It's pretty obvious the data sets don't fit.
From which you could conclude the second exam is easier and you'll have to reject the first year.

Comment: The sample size in the first case gives you more confidence that the mean and standard deviation values are close to the actual sample mean and standard deviation.  That doesn't address the question of whether the samples are the same.  The use of mean/standard deviation implies you are assuming a normal distribution, which is almost certainly not correct.

Comment: @RossMillikan
Why not? That also throws a lot of statistics out the window.

Comment: @RossMillikan, I'm not assuming normal distribution.  I just calculated mean by adding up numbers and dividing by n.  I calculated standard devation by finding average distance between squares of numbers.  I haven't made any assumptions about the distribution though.

Comment: The normal distribution is convenient, but is rarely correct.  Almost all real distributions have longer tails than the normal distribution. From H. Poincare "Everyone is sure of this [that errors are normally distributed], Mr. Lippman told me one day, since the experimentalists believe that it is a mathematical theorem, and the mathematicians that it is an experimentally determined fact."

Comment: It is quite fair to compute the mean and standard deviation of any finite distribution.  The only place the normal distribution assumption comes in is when you want to translate $n\sigma$ to a probability.

Comment: It is quite fair to compute the mean and standard deviation of any finite distribution.  The only place the normal distribution assumption comes in is when you want to translate $n\sigma$ to a probability.